# Can a company donate to a non-profit to pay for services arranged for before hand?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, donation

For example - a non-profit is in need of a website. Can a company say "StackExchange" donate to a non-profit company say $5,000 in agreement that they will spend that on paying a designer for a new website? And most importantly is this donation still tax deductible?

Thanks a bunch in advance, and sorry if this isnt the proper section. This seemed like the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Donations need to be with no strings attached. In this case, you make the cash donation, a deduction, and then they pay you, in taxable income. It's a wash. Why not just give them the service for free? Otherwise this is just money going back and forth.

Comment: Well see in a perfect world giving the service for free would work but there is more demand than supply. And if a non-profit can't find a designer / developer to work on their site pro-bono, then they're stuck wasting their own time building something sub-standard or paying someone to do it for them. And if they're going to pay someone to do it for them, why not allow a company who could benefit from the exposure front the costs? I understand it's kind of a grey situation but my intentions are good, this wasn't a seek for backdooring the system.

Comment: Thinking about it now, couldn't the company front the costs for a non-profit company to get the web design or development they need, and then write it off as a form of promotion or advertising?

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear. Donate $XXX to charity. Write it off as a deduction. They hire you and pay you $XXX as a fee. Claim the income. It's a wash. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Your time and expertise can't be taken as a deduction.

Comment: There are three parties involved. So a non-profit needs design work. Big software company "CompanyX" will sponsor the project and pay the money to a designer. Designer sees the project as any regular project and gets paid. Non-profit got what they needed, Company was able to get some advertising and write off the costs as a donation. Designer got work and claims the money as income just like any other project. Would "CompanyX" giving the non-profit the money under the condition they spent it on "web design" disqualify it's validity?  I apologize in advance, I think I'm the one not being clear.

Comment: @Gk3Biz the answer is simple: **no**. If you put conditions - it is no longer a tax-deductible charitable contribution.

Comment: @littleadv: Is that really true in general?  Does this mean that people who donate, e.g., to a university, with the stipulation that the funds will be used to build a building named after them, cannot deduct that as a charitable donation?

Comment: @BrenBarn - I donate, and for the homeless vets, can designate "training" or "shelter cost". For the School for the blind, I can similarly direct to "new braille machine", etc. That's not what the issue is. It's the Quid Pro Quo that's not permitted. I can't donate to a shelter and say "give my cousin a room." And I imagine that the IRS can discount a deduction if I donate $1M to a school to name a building. There's value in having "JoeTaxpayer Wing" at my university.

Comment: @BrenBarn I believe naming a building that the university is raising money for after them is not considered "strings attached", but forcing the university to build a building using a specific builder - definitely is.

Comment: @littleadv - I think neither of us has evidence for the Naming value, but I ask you to consider the cost of naming a stadium. A wing at a prestigious university or hospital is pure marketing.

Comment: Right, okay, I understand there are different degrees of conditions.  I'm just saying it seems a bit extreme to say "any condition at all makes the donation non-deductible".

Comment: @Joe wings and buildings in universities are *usually* named after people, most likely dead. They don't earn from their name being on the university in any way. Stadiums, on the other hand, are named by corporations, usually not yet defunct, who earn "free" advertisement during every event. Naming a stadium is **not** a donation - its an *advertisement expense*. Your analogy is false.

Comment: We are off on a tangent here. We've both answered the OP's issue. My answer stands, my comment is likely wrong, but at least provoked discussion. If you can't imagine Donald Trump deciding that defacing chunks of New York's skyline with his name wasn't enough, that he'd start putting his name on schools and hospitals via such donations, I understand. Again, I acknowledge I am probably wrong, but I'd like to see the IRS set him straight under such a circumstance. Done with this thread.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "donate", it usually assumes charitable donation with, in this context, tax benefit. That is not what happens in your scenario.

Giving someone money with the requirement of that someone to spend that money at your shop is **not** donation. It is a grant. You can do that, but you won't be able to deduct this as charitable donation, but the money paid to you back would be taxable income to you.

I respectfully disagree with Joe that its a wash. It is not. You give them money that you cannot deduct as an expense (as it is not business expense) or donation (as strings are attached). But you do give them the money, it is no longer yours. When they use the money to pay you back - that same money becomes your taxable income.

End result: you provide service, and you're the one paying (taxes) for it. Why would you do that?

Comment: No problem! I started with "no conditions," which you agree with, but go on to show how that's not even the issue. Either way, we agree the answer is No.

Answer (score 1):

Can a company say "StackExchange" donate to a non-profit company say $5,000 in agreement that they will spend that on paying a designer for a new website? And most importantly is this donation still tax deductible?

A non-profit would have to typically create a bucket for IT Services or Website design.
As long as "StackExchange" specify they employ a profession service to get it done, there would be no issue. If "StackExchange" were to specify an individula/company it would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

People put conditions on donations all the time. They donate to the Red Cross for a specific disaster. The donate money to a church for the building fund. They donate money to a hospital to buy a new x-ray machine. They donate money to the scouts for a new dining hall.

It is possible to donate money to a non-profit for a specific purpose. If the non-profit doesn't want to accept the money with those strings they can refuse. Generally these specific projects are initiated by the non-profit. But there is no requirement that the idea originate with the non-profit.

It is also up to the non-profit and their legal advisers regarding how strictly they view those strings. If you donate money for web design and they don't spend it all, can they pay net years hosting bill with the money, or must they hold it for a few years for when they need a designer again?

If the company wants to provide the service, they can structure the project to pay their employees for their time. They pay employees for $100 of labor while deigning the website. The pay and benefits reduce profit thus lowering taxes.

Donating money to the non-profit to be given back to the company doesn't seem to be the best way to structure transaction. At best it is a wash.

Donating money to a charity and then directing exactly which contractor will perform the service starts to look like money laundering, and most charities will get wary.

Comment: that is incorrect. When you donate to a specific disaster relief or a church building fund - you're not putting conditions, you're donating for a cause **the charity** came up with. You're making a choice among what's available, not conditioning your donation on something **you** desire.

Comment: They can refuse the money if they don't want it with those strings. They also can negotiate the strings. But if they agree with you, then you can deduct it, especially if you don't pick the contractor, it i deductible. Many a non-profit has competed for funding, when a rich person starts waving around money. I am sure that some renovation projects are only started because of donor approaches the charity.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: What you are saying is what happens in practise. However in the true sense of law, Quid Pro Quo is not allowed. With some large donations there are some informal agreements ... if its established it formal, the law would not allow it. A generic direction on usage of Charity funds as pointed by Joe in comments to his answers is fine. At times if there is no such category, a large donor can influence and create such a category. Ask specific way of spending by employing "X" person or company would be an issue.

Comment: I think my answer covers all the options: no strings, some strings, very specific strings.

Comment: What I disagreed with was the first sentence.